# Unable to run "heroku login" on Mac

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I installed Heroku CLI and ran heroku login command. I entered my credentials and this error came up :

```
 ▸    HTTP Error: https://api.heroku.com/login 410 Gone
 ▸    Invalid response from API.
 ▸    HTTP 410
 ▸    {my-email-id my-heroku-password}
 ▸    
 ▸    Are you behind a proxy?
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy
```

Then I ran these commands :

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
```

Then this error came-up :

```
▸    Post https://api.heroku.com/login: http: error connecting to proxy https://proxy.server.com:portnumber: dial tcp: lookup tcp/portnumber: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Searched all over google but was not able to find anything helpful. I am new to this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran 'heroku' on my command and after that it will be added on your system then you may run "heroku login" and put valid credentials